# Ruby on Rails 4 - config.consider_all_requests_local = true in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, production-environment

In `config/environments/production.rb` I can set `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` to be able to see the errors with good info for debugging, but this will also show the error to users.

In `production ENV` how is it possible to add `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` **Only for my IP address** while others see 404 or 500 error?

Or is it any work around for it?

*PS: I am using ruby on rails 4.2.4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For staging and production envs I prefer using https://github.com/errbit/errbit paired with https://airbrake.io/ service (with free plan) to collect and process all errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's the best way to go to solve your errors.

You should **temporary** lower your `config.log_level` to `:debug` to see all details about your errors, solve it, then set it back to `:info`.

You can also use any tracking tool of your application bugs as papertrail, airbrake or new_relic, to monitor your app and analyse your logs.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this would be to either use a staging server and reproduce any error there and/or use a service such as Airbrake or Bugsnag to record all the details of the error without exposing them to the user.

Rails itself does not include any functionality to do what you want. You could probably write a Rack middleware that allows you to do exactly what you want though. You can have a look at https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors, they allow you to whitelist IPs out of the box it looks like. Their code is likely to be good reading if you which to go at it alone as well so ...